# utf for both emoticons and non english languages

Tags: mysql

I have data that has emoticons and data that is in languages such as hindi, kannada, japanese etc

When I use utf8mb4, the data that has emoticons gets inserted , but not the data with other languages

When I use utf8, data with other languages gets inserted but not emoticons.

The mysql is on amazon rds

So, what must I use to solve the above issues?

Any ideas on this would be of great help

Thanks in advance
Rathi

Comment: I think you need to define "emoticons" better. Sounds like you don't have simple emoticons like :) ;) ;D etc

Comment: Yes there are no simple emoticons. There are all kinds of emoticons coming in. And I have no control on the incoming data. Also, the mysql is on amazon rds

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Amazon rds, but could you update your answer with a few example emoticons ?

Comment: Hi, this is the smiley that is not getting inserted in the table '' .. Its a simple one, but giving the problem ,1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x98' for column 'i' at row 1